# Is there a Collection that works like a Dictionary without the values?

Tags: .net, data-structures, collections, dictionary

I need a collection that works just like a Dictionary/Hashtable in a sense that it will only contain 1 instance of a given object at any time. A generic class would be preferable, but I'll take what I can get. Does this collection live somewhere in the framework?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`HashSet<T>` from `System.Core.dll`