# Does a set work like a dictionary without values?

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime

This question is the python version of: [Is there a Collection that works like a Dictionary without the values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337574/is-there-a-collection-that-works-like-a-dictionary-without-the-values)

I want a data structure that has a list of english words in it, but not their definitions.

Basically: given a sequence of letters, I want to be able to do constant-time O(1) lookup to determine if that sequence is in the english dictionary.

Would a `set()` or `frozenset()` be the correct choice?

I know that I could use a dictionary where each key's value is `None`, but that seems like a waste of memory space.

Comment: What do you mean by _given a sequence of letters?_ Assuming there is a word `apocalypse` in your dictionary, do you expect to get true by looking up `apoca` or `lypse`?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `set` is the right tool for this job. You can find out whether a word is in the set with `in`, which operates in O(1) time. Adding words is done with the `add` member which takes amortized O(1) time. It additionally has all the usual finite-set operations: union, intersection, difference, etc.:

```
>>> A = set(["foo", "bar", "baz"])
>>> B = set(["foo", "ham", "spam"])
>>> "foo" in A
True
>>> "bar" in B
False
>>> A | B
set(['bar', 'ham', 'spam', 'foo', 'baz'])
>>> A & B
set(['foo'])
>>> A - B
set(['bar', 'baz'])
>>> B - A
set(['ham', 'spam'])
```

Comment: I'm confused: what are the advantages of using `re` instead of `in`?

Comment: @bluepnume: it takes less memory. Removed it because it's apparently distracting.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Set lookup is O(1) in the *average case*, much to my surprise honestly. The [implementation](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/setobject.c?view=markup) is supposed to be close to what you describe (a dictionary with dummy values). See also [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949310/how-is-cpythons-set-implemented).

For more information on time complexities refer to:

http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

It's not built in or included in any module I know of, but perhaps you should take a look at the [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) data structure in case you need some of its properties in the future.

Comment: It was a typo. The link shows the right information, indeed. Sorry about that, should have proofread.

Comment: Ah, makes a lot more sense now :)

Answer (score 0):

Sets have *O(1)* [membership tests](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity#set) *on average* and a nice interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Big-O, but here's what the Python Language References says about [set types](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#index-25):

> Common uses for sets are **fast membership testing**, removing duplicates from a sequence, and computing mathematical operations such as intersection, union, difference, and symmetric difference.